# How to save a graph definition to a file in C++ API for Tensorflow?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

In Tensorflow image recognition tutorial you can see [ReadTensorFromImageFile](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc#L86) function.

How can I store the graph definition of the graph in this function in a protobuf file? (similar to `tf.train.write_graph`)

Note that this is very easy to do in python,but I cannot find a way to do this in C++ (at least not in the [C++ API documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/cc/index.html)).